# Security connection Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have a question about a desktop application that I am creating in java, and it is in the login part. It turns out that I don't know how to do the secure login, I do it through Sockets, but the question is that it is an application that will be public, so I don't know how to use SSL Socket without using a password for everyone, which would be hackable, could you help me? I currently have this code to see it in a simple example in a message.

For the server

```
//static ServerSocket variable
    private static ServerSocket server;
    //socket server port on which it will listen
    private static int port = 9876;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        //create the socket server object
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        //keep listens indefinitely until receives 'exit' call or program terminates
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Waiting for the client request");
            //creating socket and waiting for client connection
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            //read from socket to ObjectInputStream object
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //convert ObjectInputStream object to String
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
            //create ObjectOutputStream object
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            //write object to Socket
            oos.writeObject("Hi Client "+message);
            //close resources
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();
            //terminate the server if client sends exit request
            if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
        //close the ServerSocket object
        server.close();
    }

}
```

For the client

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
        //get the localhost IP address, if server is running on some other IP, you need to use that
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
            //establish socket connection to server
            socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 9876);
            //write to socket using ObjectOutputStream
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Sending request to Socket Server");
            if(i==4)oos.writeObject("exit");
            else oos.writeObject(""+i);
            //read the server response message
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message: " + message);
            //close resources
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want to achieve two things here. Securing a channel to ensure integrity and confidentiality would be the first one. Authentication of the client would be the second. Writing your own TLS support over the sockets would be hard and error prone. It might be easier to write your own symmetric encryption and store the secrets on bots server and client side locally. This would authenticate the client to the server too. But the question is - how many clients will there be? One? Will the code of the client be public?

Comment: The other Idea would be to use a server and a standard that already supports TLS out of the box like write your own REST endpoint and deploy it on Tomcat. Secure it all with TLS. Make your client connect over TLS. Standard stuff.

Comment: The app will have like 500clients. But how can I do cliente and server with the same simetric password, how can I send the password to the client. And the app will be in Java, so any people can decompile the code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle 500 clients this way - forget sockets and implementing TLS handling manually. Go for Spring Boot or something similar. [Make the server expose a REST endpoint to the world](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). [Secure it with Spring Security to get the authentication you want](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/). [Then deploy your own certificates to protect the communication channel](https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/). In the end [use the Springs RestTemplate so the client connects in a secure manner](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template).

Writing ad hoc code like you did above gives you a quick entry into the web communication, but makes every next step harder along the way.

Comment: Why I can't use sockets?

Comment: And it's not a web, it's a Java desktop application.

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to implement TLS using sockets. And desktop applications can use all kind of web protocols too, like REST, HTTP and so on. It is a common practice to write desktop applications using these protocols.

Comment: Can you send me an example please?

Comment: Please refer to the links I have provided. You might want to start with playing with the RestTemplate to see, how to query REST and HTTP endpoints without having a browser. This will be a bit of a drawback when you need to research so many things before really start coding, but it will be worth it.

Comment: While I appreciate and agree with your focus on using higher-level protocols and tools, I feel like you are overstating the difficulty of using TLS in Java. Java has support for TLS sockets for both the server and the client. The API's are very similar to the Socket APIs.